# I am merging my two profiles of Stack Overflow but it is showing 'Not a valid profile' link while it is valid

Tags: discussion, login

My two profile links are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4503691/attraction) and [that](https://stackexchange.com/users/7325245/dinesh).

There is so much validation on Stack Overflow that I am not receiving proper help.

An hour ago my profile was working but after that it became invalid, how?

I was able to post this question in Meta as it require 5 reputation but how will a person get help if new to this site?

Comment: The link you provided for the user *Dinesh* is from Meta Stackexchange, which is not the same as the one on Stackoverflow. Use this link instead and try it again: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5579827/dinesh ; if it really doesn't work, use the contact form with *Other* and put the links in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be because you are trying to merge profiles from two different platforms.

The first profile - https://stackoverflow.com/users/4503691/attraction is from stackoverflow.

But, the other one - https://stackexchange.com/users/7325245/dinesh is from stackexchange.

That is why it is saying that the stackexchange profile is not a valid stackoverflow profile.

If this - https://stackoverflow.com/users/5579827/dinesh is your profile on stackoverflow with the name dinesh, then try merging using this one.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please sign into either account, visit the contact form and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. Later the stack exchange team will co-ordinate accordingly and guide you.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Yes I have tried this but it is showing that my this profile http://stackexchange.com/users/7325245/dinesh is invalid